# how to negate and select in the same charset

Tags: regex

this must be fairly simple but i can't seems to find answer of it

hypothetically what want is to select all the number but 3 using charset

regx = `[0-9]` and `[^3]` at the same time like `[0-9^3]` but regX engine will not allow it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use negative lookahead for this:

```
/(?!3)[0-9]/
```

... but usually it's easier to exclude the unwanted character from the charclass itself:

```
/[0-24-9]/
```

The second approach is far more beneficial when you want in fact to match any number of such characters: compare this...

```
/^[0-24-9]*$/
```

... with this:

```
/^(?!.*3)[0-9]*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like

```
[0-24-9]
```

this will include all digits but the 3.

I think the nested character class you tried is only supported in a few regex flavours. E.g. in .net you should be able to do something like

```
[0-9-[3]]
```

[See regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xmlcharclass.html)